# PayPal REST API - Express Checkout - How to change default language?

Tags: php, rest, paypal, express-checkout

Using the [PayPal REST API endpoint for an Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create), if PayPal doesn't recognize the customer by a cookie, the checkout page is displayed according to the region of the merchant account. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

> You can change the locale of PayPal pages to match the language on
>   your website using either a 2-character country code or a 5-character
>   locale code from the supported codes listed on the NVP/SOAP API locale
>   codes page. To change the language displayed on the PayPal pages, set
>   the LOCALECODE parameter to one of the allowable values in the
>   SetExpressCheckout call

This example sets `LOCALCODE` to `ES` for **Spain**.

```
[requiredSecurityParameters]
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=https://...
&CANCELURL=https://...
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&LOCALECODE=ES
```

#### Visit [Paypal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/) to learn more.

Comment: Unfortunately this is another API - I'm using REST

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an [HTTP header `Accept-Language`](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) with one of the following codes: [Supported locale codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/locale-codes/#supported-locale-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Well, [RTFM](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/locale-codes/#localize-the-checkout-experience).

I ended up creating a new Web Experience Profile, which allows to set the locale code. The Web Experience Profile ID can be passed to the ExpressCheckout API call.

Note: When querying the endpoint that [lists all Web Experience profiles](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#web-profile_get-list), PayPal does **not** return temporary profiles. You need to write down the ID you get from the create response.